# Does anyone know of any good open source voting software?

Tags: collaboration, polling, voting, voting-system

I'm looking for a voting system that we can implement at work amongst our developers.

We need something that allows developers to submit ideas about what we can do to improve our development practices (amongst other things) and then have all the developers vote on the ideas to give everyone an idea of what ideas we should attempt to implement first. For example, our developers could list ideas for parts of our code base that should be improved/cleaned up and we'd be able to collectively vote on which parts to start on first.

Something like www.uservoice.com might be one way of getting what we need but I'm still wanting to look at alternatives.

Unfortunately, googling for voting and polling systems just doesn't seem to bring up any useful results because most of them seem geared towards elections and surveys rather than a way for people to make suggestions and vote on them.

Does anyone here know of any sort of software system that might be able to do what I'm looking for? Better yet, does anyone have such a system set up for the developers at their work place? I'd be interested in knowing if it is useful at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at [Idea Torrent](http://www.ideatorrent.org/)? It has nice UI, you can submit ideas, and people comment and vote for them. Haven't used myself, but it's adopted by SourceForge and Ubuntu.

Comment: That's pretty much exactly what I'm after. And since it's been used by teams such as the one behind Ubuntu I reckon it will work fairly well. Thanks heaps!